# Angular 6 - How to work with array in json result from Web API

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api, angular6

I am new to Angular so sorry for maybe stupid question.
I have this JSON result from .NET Core Web API:

```
{
    "id": "4ed2c6d4-eb58-4853-b69a-1b7db3aa3f4a",
    "h24d": 156123,
    "Gu": [
        {
            "id": "94617ded-3e9f-40e7-8ab2-42ea62b6dad2",
            "caseId": "4ed2c6d4-eb58-4853-b69a-1b7db3aa3f4a",
            "gu01d": "9110"
        },
        {
            "id": "5736fda5-7619-4bf6-9c12-f4b2e9def38e",
            "caseId": "4ed2c6d4-eb58-4853-b69a-1b7db3aa3f4a",
            "gu01d": "9113"
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to put these data into angular 6 page. I have done an edit of master data and I try to work on sub data Gu. Ideal will be dynamically adding of text inputs. Loading to **`[(ngModel)]="case.gu[0].gu01d"`** is working fine but it is not ideal way I think. But when I save data into a new case, `case.gu[]` is empty and I don't know how to work with this data.

Could someone help me please? Thank you very much.

There is part of source code:
Typescript code:

```
import { Component, Inject, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';
import { NgForm, NgModel } from '@angular/forms';
import { getBaseUrl } from '../../app.browser.module';
import { HttpClientModule, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

@Component({
    selector: 'customsCase',
    templateUrl: './customsCase.component.html',
})

export class CustomsCaseComponent {
    public retPostData: any;

    public template: any;

    public case!: CustomsCase;
    public state: string | undefined;
    public stateId: any | undefined;
    public id: string;
    enter code here
    constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private http: Http, @Inject('BASE_URL') baseUrl: string) {
        this.id = this.route.snapshot.params["id"];
        http.get(baseUrl + 'api/CustomsCases/' + this.id).subscribe(result => {
            this.case = result.json() as CustomsCase;
        }, error => console.error(error));
        http.get(this.stateId).subscribe(result => {
            this.state = this.stateId;
        }, error => console.error(error));

    }

    public Save() {
        const url = getBaseUrl();
        this.http.post(url + 'api/CustomsCases', this.case).subscribe
            (data => { this.retPostData = data; });
    }
}

export interface CustomsCase {
    id: string | undefined;
    h24d: string | undefined;
    gu: Gu[];
}
export class Gu {
    gu01d: string | undefined;
}
```

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/bs-datepicker.css">
</head>
<body>
    <table max-width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td>H24D</td>
            <td><input type="text" title="H24D" [(ngModel)]="case.h24d" name="case.h24d" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><b>GU</b></td>
        </tr>
        <tr *ngIf="case.id != null && case.gu[0].gu01d != null">
            <td>GU01D</td>
            <td><input type="text" title="GU01D" [(ngModel)]="case.gu[0].gu01d" name="case.gu01d" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr *ngIf="case.id == null">
            <td>GU01D</td>
            <td><input type="text" title="GU01D" [(ngModel)]="case.gu[0].gu01d" name="case.gu01d" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr *ngIf="case.id != null && case.gu[1].gu01d != null">
            <td>GU01D</td>
            <td><input type="text" title="GU01D" [(ngModel)]="case.gu[1].gu01d" name="case.gu01d" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr *ngIf="case.id == null">
            <td>GU01D</td>
            <td><input type="text" title="GU01D" [(ngModel)]="case.gu[1].gu01d" name="case.gu01d" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <button type="Button" (click)="Save()">Save</button>

</body>
</html>
```

I have one page for create and update so there is a lot of if conditions.

Comment: Please show the code of your component. Both typescript and html-template.

Comment: Added to original question

Comment: Do you get any errors when you use a new `CustomsCase`? How do you create an new object of type `CustomsCase`? It'd be good if you'd add the related code to your post/question above.

Comment: I am create new object of CustomsCase as **this.case = { } as CustomsCase;** in constructor. One error in console when I want create - Cannot read property '0' of undefined - on italic markup line <tr *ngIf="case.id == null">
            <td>GU01D</td>
            _<td><input type="text" title="GU01D" [(ngModel)]="case.gu[0].gu01d" name="case.gu01d" /></td>_
        </tr>

Comment: I tried something and this is work good - editing existing gu01d. But only when somre records are in table. Now I need solution for new case and I dont know how to solve it.
`<table>
        <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let g of case.gu; let i= index;">
                <td>
                    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="g.gu01d">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>`

Answer (score 0):

Try to instantiate it this way:

```
case: any;

constructor() {

    this.case = new CustomsCase();

    console.log(this.case);
} 

export interface ICustomsCase {
    id?: string | undefined;
    h24d: string | undefined;
    gu: Gu[];
}

export class CustomsCase implements ICustomsCase {
    h24d = undefined;
    gu: Array<Gu> = [{gu01d: ''}];
}

export class Gu {
    gu01d: string | undefined;
}
```

Whatsmore, you can prevent the `0 from undefined`-error if you use the Elvis-Operator `?.` with `[(ngModel)]`

```
[(ngModel)]="case?.gu[0]?.gu01d"
[(ngModel)]="case?.gu[1]?.gu01d"
```

or

```
[(ngModel)]="g?.gu01d"
```

This operator checks layer for layer whether the next member actually exists before trying to access it.

Comment: I will try that. But I need some tip how can I do in HTML template more inputs for new records of Gu to one new case. It is 1:N relationship and it is not clear how many inputs will be. So I need dynamic render of it.

Comment: Do you want to directly show these new entries afterwards?

Comment: Yes, showing it will be very good.

Your code is working nice. Line **gu: Array<Gu> = [{gu01d: ''}];** is making one instance of Gu and I am see it in model to WebAPI on saving. So is there any solution to make N instances? For example on button add new gu will make new input for new instance.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to you second question I'd suggest a slightly different approach.

Your HTML-template stays as you already tried.

```
<table> 
    <tbody> 
        <tr *ngFor="let g of case?.gu; let i= index;"> 
            <td> 
                <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="g?.gu01d"> 
           </td> 
        </tr> 
    </tbody> 
</table>

<button type="Button" (click)="Save()">Save</button>
<button type="Button" (click)="addNewGU()">New</button>
```

But you now use the proposed new-Button to add a new object to `case.gu`.

```
case: any;

constructor() {

    this.case = new CustomsCase();

    console.log(this.case);
} 

// adds a new gu-object to the list
// this object will be shown as empty input then in the table
private addNewGU(): void {
    let gu = {gu01d: ''};
    this.case.gu.push(gu);
}

export interface ICustomsCase {
    id?: string | undefined;
    h24d: string | undefined;
    gu: Gu[];
}

export class CustomsCase implements ICustomsCase {
    h24d = undefined;
    gu: Array<Gu> = [{gu01d: ''}];
}

export class Gu {
    gu01d: string | undefined;
}
```

This creates the expected 1:n situation.

Alternatively you can let your `Save()`-method implicitly call the `addNewGU()` method. But this will lead to an always empty last object in your list.

Comment: Here you go. Try it. Watch out for the additional Elvis-Operator in the `ngFor`-loop!

Comment: Your welcome. Please, don't forget to mark this answer as solution. And an upvote would be nice too, though. ;)